# Coding the transpose function for a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, 3d, transpose

The goal is to

> Implement a routine to transpose a 3-channel RGB image. 
>   The hints:
>   Hint : if the input has size (h,w,3) then the output should have size (w,h,3).

The image is defined as
given below:

> image = rand(10, 8, 3)

The exercise asks to not use "transpose" function from numpy library.
The goal is to write a "transpose" function ourselves.
I named it transposeImage, and it takes in an image, (the one i mentioned above).
This is what i did:

> def transposeImage(image):

```
result = array([image[0].T, image[1].T])
```

> return result

It gives me the following error:

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Can you please help?

Comment: What does it mean to transpose a 3D array? I've only ever heard of it for 2D arrays (matrices actually — e.g. [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)).

Comment: Is this a 3d `numpy.ndarray`?  Then is already has a transpose *method*.  The `arr.T` uses it.

Comment: What is `Image.shape`?  Make sure the code you show us matches the error message.

Comment: Explain why you can't use transpose.  What are you supposed to be learning?  The exercise must have a purpose?

Comment: `.T` on a (a,b,c) produces a (c,b,a) shape.  Numpy transpose works be changing shape and strides; it does copy or 'rearrange' the array values.